# How can I access the variable of the outer class?

Tags: python, file, class

I have three files: one for the game, one for the main menu, and one for the options. Because entire other files are one class, I have another file that determines which class is called. Now in my game file, which is one class) I made another class for the purposes of the game, so an inner class. However, if I want to call a variable of the outer class in the inner, "self" doesn't work, and neither does "insert name of the outer class" work. So how can I call the variable of the outer class?

Comment: You need some actual code in your question, but don't use nested classes in Python. There's little reason to do so, since it's perfectly legal to define multiple classes in the same file, unlike in Java.

Comment: Okay, I will try your approach and post the results.